# Web Component Tester: Apply afterEach() globally

Tags: polymer, mocha.js, web-component-tester

I have hundreds of Polymer test suites. At the end of each test, I'd like to do some custom quality checks. Is there a way to do this globally for all my test suites?

Answer (score 4):

After going through some source code I found a solution. There is an `extraScripts` config option that can be passed to Web Component Tester. Specify your global `afterEach` in a separate JS file and include it here.

`// Additional .js files to include in *generated* test indexes.`